# 2 stdClass Object foreach PHP

Tags: php, html, oop, curl

Been searching for a solution for my problem. Seams meny has the same q as me, but still haven't got a solution for my problem.

I have a stdClass Object that needs to be printed out in a foreach or somlike like that.

Here is a cut of the result i get with a "print_r($result->ukuran->[0])".

```html
This no random 31608111
stdClass Object
    (
        [31608111] => stdClass Object
```

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [31608111] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 31608111
            [nama] => Sepatu Gunung Pria - TMS 090
            [sku] => TMS 090
            [harga_member] => 322500
            [berat] => 1500
            [deskripsi] => Sepatu Gunung Pria Berkualitas Produk Asli Bandung
            [long_deskripsi] => Hobi mendaki gunung atau aktifitas outdoor lainnya? Tetap tampil trendy dan modis dengan Fashion Outdoor dari Trekking Brand Perlengkapan Ourdoor Asal Bandung. Sepatu Gunung Pria dengan bahan KULIT BUK ini dijamin awet!

Tersedia Ukuran: 39-43
            [kategori] => Sepatu Wanita
            [ukuran] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 39
                    [1] => 40
                    [2] => 41
                    [3] => 42
                    [4] => 43
                )

            [warna] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Perlengkapan Outdoor
                    [1] => Sepatu Gunung
                    [2] => Perlengkapan Naik Gunung
                    [3] => Sepatu Trekking
                )

            [foto] => https://s1.bandros.co.id/2016/thumb/trekking/1-TMS-090.jpg
            [foto_gallery] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://s1.bandros.co.id/2016/trekking/1-TMS-090.jpg
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: form submits to home.php.  is "PHP CURL not sucses [sic]" the home.php file? the question is very unclear and probably contains a lot more code than is necessary to ask the question...whatever the question is.

Comment: You can only loop objects that implement the [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface and `stdClass` obviously doesn't. I think you should ask yourself why you have a non-iterable object in the first place.

Comment: BTW, have you reused your previous question to host a brand new one??

Comment: `foreach($result->ukuran->[0] as $id => $obj) { echo $obj->id . ' ' . $obj->nama; // etc }`